# How to make nsurldatatask completion handler to run initially?

Tags: objective-c, completionhandler, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am using nsurldatatask and getting some data through it and populate that data in tableview. However, i am unable to get data for the first time rather Iam getting it for second time and initial output is getting as null in my tableview. How to get the completion handler run in one go such that I can able to get data from beginning it self.
{

I am writing in shortform:

```
-void(getResponseData)
{ 
    nsurl,
    urlsession,
    datatask 
    and data
```

[datatask resume];
     }

now I am using this method in didselectrowatindex delgate to get the current data and show it in detail viewcontroller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{ 

    AppDelegate *ap = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 

    ap.row = indexPath.row; 

    [self getResponseData]; (*********) (Here Iam using the Datatask Method)

    if(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil) 

    {

        DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"]; 

        detail.paragraphText = ap.paragraph_ad; detail.currentPage = indexPath.row+1; 

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES]; 

        [self emptyingArrays]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: "i am unable to get data for the first time rather Iam getting it for second time and initial output is getting as null": My guess is that you didn't understood the async part of that method. Show your code.

Comment: I am writing in shortform                                                                                  -void(getResponseData){  nsurl,urlsession,datatask and data} [datatask resume]; now I am using this method in didselectrowatindex delgate to get the current data and show it in detail viewcontroller.

Comment: Edit your question with your code and format it, do not post it in comment, it's unreadable.

Comment: If you do a print in `getResponseData` method after `[datatask resume];` and in the `completionHandler`, you'll see that it's called before. Your task is async.

Comment: How to make it sync sir, as I want to get the data for first instance such that it should go to the completion handler before datatask resume????

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the data being loaded from network? Display in the detail view controller?

Comment: yes indeed,sir. I am trying to display the data in detailviewcontroller of the cell which is currently selected. but the data is coming null at first load such that detailviewcontroller shows null value but in second load(any cell selected) the previous data gets shown which is incorrect.

Comment: Don't make it synchronous. Create a completionBlock, for the `getResponseData` method. Once your request is done, push the new VC. I'd suggest a HID to show the user to wait.

Comment: Why not implement and call [self getResponseData]; in the detailed view controller's view did load method. If you require data specific to the cell that was selected then pass it on to the detail view controller after instantiating it.  OR if you need to load the data before presenting the detailed view controller do what @Larme said.

Comment: Actually sir I have multiple json data retrieval methods such that they are called in two different methods and being used in didSelectRowAtIndex method of the tableview such that to get data corresponding to that particular indexpath which acts as input to the json methods,i.e..,getResponseData and also another method which is called inside of getResponseData method.\